# Angular - Can't get json data from $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Im working on this google maps project but I can't get the json to work

```
angular
.module('angular-google-maps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.controller('mainController', controller);

function controller ($scope, $http, $filter) {
   $http.get('/data/markers.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.markers = data;
   });

   $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 52.339287,
        longitude: 4.925805
      },
      zoom: 8,
      markers: $scope.markers
   };

 $scope.options = {};

};
```

If I understand correctly I can just get the data by using $scope.markers right?

Comment: the `.success` method has been deprecated, you should use `.then`.  Also, you need to make sure that your `data` object actually contains what you are expecting. I would `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`, you are probably not accessing this object as you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate not. When you assign `$scope.markers = data;` you are changing the object that the variable is referencing, but `$scope.map.makers` is still referencing the old value (which is `undefined`).

Two of the simplest ways to over come this:

1) Reference the variable derectly:

```
$http.get('/data/markers.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.map.markers = data;
   $scope.markers = data;
 });
```

2) With a watch:

```
$scope.markers = null;
$http.get('/data/markers.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.markers = data;
 });

// This is fired whenever makers is changed
$scope.$watch('makers', function(value) { 
    $scope.map.markers = value; 
});
```

Comment: No worries :) Hope this helped! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use `then` method and modify the `map` object in the callback :

```
 $http.get('/data/markers.json').then(function(data) {
      $scope.markers = data;
      $scope.map.markers = data;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.markers = data; calls after async request, so your markers: $scope.markers call undefined $scope.markers

Answer (score 0):

You were not getting data in  $scope.map.markers because value of data from  http is asynchronous and  $scope.markers  is not initialized

TRY:

```
 angular
    .module('angular-google-maps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('mainController', controller);

function controller ($scope, $http, $filter) {
   $http.get('/data/markers.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.markers = data;

   $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 52.339287,
        longitude: 4.925805
      },
      zoom: 8,
      markers: $scope.markers
   };

 $scope.options = {};
   });


};
```